# What does the colored bar mean under GitHub repository?

Tags: github, colors, repository

[image: github colored bar]

There have a multi coloured bar under github repository status bar.

What does this color bar mean in github?

Comment: A simple click on the bar would help you find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors indicate the percentage of what language the repository is programmed in. Simply clicking over the colored bar will show the language along with the percentage of that language in the repository.

[image: Percentage of langauge]